# Getting the executable name in Linux from /proc/ and detect if it's truncated

Tags: linux, process, proc

The executable name is linux can be read in various ways.

1. By reading /proc/[pid]/comm, which contains a string that's truncated after reaching 16 characters or TASK_COMM_LEN.
2. By reading /proc/[pid]/cmdline which contains the command line used with arguments.

There are other ways like reading /proc/[pid]/stat, or /proc/[pid]/status, but they are similar to 1.

In case of Point 1, the [proc(5)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/procfs.5.html) man page says:

> The filename of the executable, in parentheses.
> Strings longer than TASK_COMM_LEN (16) characters
> (including the terminating null byte) are silently
> truncated.  This is visible whether or not the
> executable is swapped out.

---

I have 3 processes that I see mismatch and highlight them (on my system right now):

1. PID 7610
2. PID 38193
3. PID 37030

Consider these cases:

1. PID 7610:

- The content of `/proc/7610/comm` is `Web Content`
- But the content of `/proc/7610/cmdline` is
  `/opt/firefox-developer-edition/firefox-bin-contentproc-childID17-isForBrowser-prefsLen7837-prefMapSize238232-parentBuildID20201215185920-appdir/opt/firefox-developer-edition/browser4080truetab`

2. PID 38193:

- The content of `/proc/38193/comm` is `zyxwvutsrqponml`
- But the content of `/proc/38193/cmdline` is `/ramdisk/abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz./zyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba`

There's a `\u0000` between `ramdisk/abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz` and `./zyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba` that I can see programmatically, which I replace with `\s`.

3. PID 37030

- The content of `/proc/37030/comm` is `kworker/3:1-xfs-reclaim/sda2`
- The content of `/proc/37030/cmdline` is empty.

---

- In case 1, we see that the cmdline and comm are totally different.
- In case 2, we see that the cmdline shows the whole command, but comm is truncated to 15 characters.
- In case 3, we see that the cmdline is empty, but comm isn't truncated as it's supposed to be.

How does the file comm contains "kworker/3:1-xfs-reclaim/sda2" without getting truncated to 15 places (+ \n to be 16)?

How do I know if it's actually truncated or not, like in the case of point 2?

Comment: Note that `/proc/7610/cmdline` contains NULs, which aren't visible in the terminal but very much exist

Comment: ...consider `cmdline=( ); while IFS= read -r -d '' piece; do cmdline+=( "$piece" ); done </proc/7610/cmdline; printf '%q ' "${cmdline[@]}"; printf '\n'` if you want to write a command-line list out to the terminal for human consumption (or written elsewhere for a shell-compatible parser to read) unambiguously.

Comment: Yes, I have mentioned `\u0000`, which is `\x00` or NUL in other words.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, an easier way to print the cmdline would be `xargs -0 echo < /proc/pid/cmdline`.

Comment: @Juergen, that's deeply buggy. Using that practice you can't tell the difference between `./program "one argument"` and `./program "one" "argument"`; the point of `printf %q` is that it escapes strings with nonprintable characters unambiguously, so you can tell the difference (f/e) between spaces and tabs, or get output that tells you how to escape a non-breaking space in such a way as to reproduce the command line that was run.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, you are right if you need to _reproduce_ the cmdline unambiguously, but in other cases readability _for human consumption_ might be preferred, like it is in the output of `ps` (without extra quoting). And while your code is more complicated, it is also faster because it doesn't call external commands :-)

Comment: @Juergen, I've seen lots of bugs caused because people try to run command lines they get off the output of `ps` (or logs generated by docker, or similar) without understanding how they need to be changed to reproduce the effects of the original quoting, so I don't think that's exactly an example of good practice.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The only reliable way is via `/proc/PID/exe`, which will work even if the executable has been removed, or it never existed in the first place (as when executing a file created with `memfd_create()` via `fexecve()` or `execveat(AT_EMPTY_PATH)`.

Both `/proc/PID/comm` and `/proc/PID/cmdline` can be easily faked by the process itself (the former via `prctl(PR_SET_NAME)`, the latter just by overwriting the `argv[]` strings).

> How does the file `comm` contains `kworker/3:1-xfs-reclaim/sda2` without getting truncated to 15 places (+ `\n` to be 16)?

That's a kernel thread, not a userland process, and different [rules](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.10.8/source/fs/proc/array.c#L105) apply ;-)